# coalesce and case when statement for postgres 9.6

Tags: sql, coalesce, case-when, postgres-9.6

I am trying to backfill some data. Column A in this table may come from multiples table and I can use coalesce function for it. If the coalesce returns null then I need to goto another table and based on the value from that table I need to insert a hard coded value to this column.

```
Backfill Table - T1
Backfill Column - Column A

Coalesce Tables - TC2, TC3, TC4, TC5,TC6
Coalesce Columns - TC2.C2, TC3.C3, TC4.C4, TC5.C5,TC6.C6

Another Table - AT1
Another Column - CAT1

If CAT1 = 21, then Column A should be 100
If CAT1 = 22, then Column A should be 200
If CAT1 = 23, then Column A should be 300
If CAT1 = 24, then Column A should be 400
```

Assume there are multiple columns to backfill, not showing here.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE T1 (COLUMN A)
SELECT
coalesce (TC2.C2, TC3.C3, TC4.C4, TC5.C5,TC6.C6),
',
',
'
FROM A JOIN TC2 blah blah;
```

I am just not sure how to include conditions or case statements for AT1 table.

Edit: I am asking about a case statement within a coalesce statement.

Comment: You question is not clear  .. try add  a proper data sample and the expcted  result  .

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE T1 (COLUMN A)
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT coalesce (TC2.C2, TC3.C3, TC4.C4, TC5.C5,TC6.C6)) IS NOT NULL
        THEN  (SELECT coalesce (TC2.C2, TC3.C3, TC4.C4, TC5.C5,TC6.C6))
        WHEN AT1.CAT1 = '21' THEN '100'
        WHEN AT1.CAT1 = '22' THEN '200'
        WHEN AT1.CAT1 = '23' THEN '300'
        WHEN AT1.CAT1 = '24' THEN '400'
    END AS NEW_COLUMN_VALUE
```

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for. Thanks!